# What should the template path be when using Spring Boot and a Sitemesh filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, sitemesh

I'm trying to make use of Sitemesh (3) templating with Spring Boot (4+) using Java annotation based config.

When I hit the controller URL, the handler method is invoked.
The Sitemesh filter is activated (debugging proves that).

However I am getting a 404, which I believe is because with the config I have the Freemarker template isn't found (wrong path somewhere).

Code follows, any suggestions what I'm doing wrong would be great!

Filter:
    @WebFilter
public class SitemeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {

```
    @Override
    protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
        System.out.println("in sitemesh filter");
        builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "templates/main.ftl")
            .setMimeTypes("text/html")
            .addExcludedPath("/javadoc/*")
            .addExcludedPath("/brochures/*");
     }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
MemberService memberService;

@RequestMapping(value="member/{id}")
public ModelAndView viewMember(@PathVariable("id") int memberId, ModelAndView mv) {
    mv.setViewName("member");
    ClubMember member = memberService.getClubMember(memberId);
    mv.addObject("member", member);
    return mv;
  }
}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ClubManagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClubManagementApplication.class, args);
    }
 }
```

Application.properties:
        spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/

My templates live in :
src/main/resources/templates   <- this is where I've put the sitemesh templates live
src/main/resources/views   <- here are the Freemarker pages

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has same issue:

templates ended up in resources/templates

sitemeshfilter:

```
        @Override
    protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
        builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/main.ftl")
            .setMimeTypes("text/html", "application/xhtml+xml",                       "application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml");
     }
```

Note nothing before '/main.ftl'